# show method is not working on sqldependency notification but showDialog working fine

Tags: c#, .net, sqldependency

```
string localConnection = 
    @"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=Test; Uid=sa; Pwd=admin";
        SqlConnection c1;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            c1 = new SqlConnection(localConnection);
            SqlDependency.Start(localConnection);
            c1.Open();
            SomeMethod();
        }

        void SomeMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

                // Create a new SqlCommand object.
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    "SELECT id, name FROM dbo.tbl1",
                    c1))
                {

                    // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    // Maintain the refence in a class member.

                    // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
                    dependency.OnChange += new
                       OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

                    // Execute the command.
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // Process the DataReader.
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            { }
        }

        // Handler method
        void OnDependencyChange(object sender,
           SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(Method1);
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
            // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
        }

        void Method1()
        {
            Window1 obj = new Window1();
            obj.Show();
            SomeMethod();
        }
```

In Method1() if i call obj.ShowDialog() in place of obj.Show(), this will be working fine. But i need to call obj.Show().

Answer (score 0):

Changes in code will be resolved this issue.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Window1 w = new Window1();
    w.Show();

    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});
```